# How to fix "git push heroku master"?

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to do it for a long time, and I never can, I keep creating files and folders, new `.git`, I try but it doesn't work! I've been wanting to host my discord py bot, but the command `git push heroku master` always gets an ERROR! Now I leave the logs! I have git installed I am logged into HEROKU and registered! I have a GITHUB account and I have repositories

```
C:\Users\ruben\Desktop\Discord\Bot\ValientBot>git push heroku master Enumerating objects: 4, done. 
Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done. 
Delta compression using up to 2 threads Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 2.57 KiB | 263.00 KiB/s, done. 
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 remote: Compressing source files... done. remote: Building source: remote: remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: 
https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure remote: remote: ! Push failed remote: ! remote: ! 
## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: eb6fced64ec14c05dd2f92e7cf40c0e2cd30a1ff remote: ! remote: ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version eb6fced64ec14c05dd2f92e7cf40c0e2cd30a1ff remote: ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch. remote: ! remote: ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run: remote: ! remote: ! git push heroku <branchname>:main remote: ! remote: ! This article goes into details on the behavior: remote: ! 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version remote: remote: Verifying deploy... remote: remote: ! Push rejected to valient-bot. remote: To https://git.heroku.com/valient-bot.git ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/valient-bot.git'
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong that doesn't work?

Comment: There are a lot of posts of the same, I do everything that the solutions say and nothing, mine is different, I do not get the same error!

Answer (score 0):

If the project you’re deploying uses main as its default branch name, use $ git push heroku main
instead of
$ git push heroku master

Heroku has updated default git branch name to main and this might be a reason for the error that you are having.